# RADEditor's elements' CSS properties not getting overridden

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, telerik

I added [this](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/editor/overriding-global-css-styles-inherited-by-radeditor.aspx) in the head section of my page as told in the article..added the following two additional lines to get rid of the background image([RADEditor](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx) on my page is inheriting master page's bg image)

```
.reContentCell
        {
            background-image:none;
            background-color:White;
            }
            .reDropDown{color:Aqua;}
```

Why are the changes not taking place?

[EDIT]

added !important to both the properties above...still can't see no change

[EDIT]

I am using RADEditor in like MANY pages soo was wondering if I can do some coding in the Master Pages ..like in Master Page I can detect if there's some radEditor in any of the ContentPlaceholders..then I can add the CSS file to be used for that Editor so it doesn't inherit master page's CSS properties...so how do i go about it ?? How do I search for radEditor in Content pages and then add CSS to it ???

[EDIT]

I have already tried the following :-

ie adding CustomSkin's CSS classes to Editor

```
<telerik:RadEditor ID="Editor1" EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="true" runat="server">

<CssFiles>

<telerik:EditorCssFile value="Skins/CustomSkin/Editor.CustomSkin.css"/>
<telerik:EditorCssFile value="Skins/CustomSkin/Editor.CustomSkin.css"/>
<telerik:EditorCssFile value="Skins/CustomSkin/Editor.CustomSkin.css"/>
 </CssFiles>

</telerik:RadEditor>
```

In the page's head section :-

I gave reference of CSS files...now its working fine..Editor is not getting screwed up or anything coz of Master page's CSS ...BUT what I want is some way to do this in the master page's code itself like I said above..plz help..thnx

[EDIT]

Master page's code behind :-

```
if(ContentPlaceHolders.Contains("what to type here??")){}
```

Intellisense is not showing Telerik RadEditor option in the drop down list

Is there some other way to add Editor's CSS files programmaticaly in master page's code behind??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
.reContentCell, .reContentCell iframe
{
background-color:#FFFFFF !important;
}
```

because the original css file is adding a background colour to both the cell and the iframe.

Comment: its not working..actually the problem is not just the background image..even the heading tags are inheriting Master page's css' properties and I can't see no change in them either..I can't do something in mAster page's code behind ? like detect editor in its content pages and then add customized css classes to it ??

Comment: It seems like the editor is getting "screwed up" because it can't find any css properties for the editor and it's falling back on the other css in your page. So set a custom skin for the editor and then override the values you want to.

Comment: Michael I did just that!..plz read my updates above..custom skin thingy is working fine...but I want to add Editor's custom CSS files programatically in Master page's code behind so i don't have to add "CssFiles" attribute in each and every aspx page that is using the editor..there are so many